# Could someone tell me if low / less is to be used here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

a) My height is low / less 
b) I feel my weight is low

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Amit. We expect people to do a little research before asking a question. In this case, you could look up low and less in a good dictionary like this one https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/less and look at the examples that they provide. If that doesn't explain everything, please update your question to include details of your research and to explain what exactly is still unclear. Also look at this: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/short

Comment: If I weighed 200 kg and I lost 10 kg, everyone would agree that my weight was less, but nobody would agree that my weight was low.

Comment: @Davo you would say that "I lost weight" not that "my weight is less."

Comment: @faraza I am showing use for the words in the original question. Are you claiming that my statement is incorrect?

Comment: I get it. So @Davo when you use "less" in this context you are actually comparing your current weight to what you used to weigh before. And since the value is smaller. You use "less"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a native English speaker, describing your height by saying "my height is less than his" or "my height is low" is not natural or common. We would say "I am shorter than him" or "I am short."

Regarding weight, you can say "My weight is low." Less is used in the context of comparison, so you could say "My weight is less than his" or you could say "My weight is lower than his" but you would not say "My weight is less" unless someone first said their own weight and you were saying that in response. However, this is still a somewhat strange way to phrase things. Most native speakers would say, "I am light" or "I am lighter than him." Saying "my weight is low" is not as strange as saying "my height is low" but it's still a bit strange.